# draw complicated symmetric figure

Tags: diagrams, pstricks, technical-drawing

I wish to draw a figure in PSTricks (a Paint-version is attached), consisting of three elements:

1. Two identical objects, facing each other (they are they in the
   figure...)
2. A red "parabola", contained within the two grey objects

How can I go about this easiest in PSTricks? Is it just brute force or is there a clever strategy? The brute-force method seems very time-consuming.

The various sizes, distances etc.. are less important at the moment. I am just trying to figure out how to do this to begin with..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PSTricks just for fun!

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\def\f(#1){(#1^2+1)/7}
\def\g(#1){(#1^2+1)/11}


\def\wall{%
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray]
    {
        \psline(-2,0)(*-2 {\f(x)})
        \psplot[algebraic]{-2}{2}{\f(x)}
        \psline(*2 {\f(x)})(2,0)
        \closepath
    }\ignorespaces
}

\def\bridge{%
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red]
    {
        \psline(-2,0)(*-2 {\g(x)})
        \psplot[algebraic]{-2}{2}{\g(x)}
        \psline(*2 {\f(x)})(2,0)
        \psplot[algebraic]{2}{-2}{-(\g(x))}
        \closepath
    }\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](4,4)
    \rput(2,2){\bridge}
    \rput{-90}(0,2){\wall}
    \rput{90}(4,2){\wall}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]